# Why are my labels in my collectionView smaller than the the dimesinsons given

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collectionview

I am using a collectionView to make labels to drag and reorder a set of numbers to make the user put the numbers in order. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!
    var str_arr = ["1", "3", "4", "5", "2"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
        collectionview.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
        longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    }
    
    @objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        switch(gesture.state) {
        case .began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionview.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionview)) else {
                break
            }
            collectionview.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        case .changed:
            collectionview.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
        case .ended:
            collectionview.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collectionview.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}

extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return str_arr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
    {
            return true
    }
    //This the ouptut part
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let item = str_arr.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
        str_arr.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
        print(str_arr)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DemoCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DemoCollectionViewCell
        cell.lbl_text.text = str_arr[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    //Size
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: ((self.view.frame.size.width/5)), height: 200);
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
}
```

The issue I run into is that when I first it, this is the screen:
[Image when I first start the iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F5Tc.png)

When I drag around the labels, they become the correct size. This is what it should look like from the beginning:
[What it should look like after dragging a label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qHkR.png)

I do not know why this happens. I think it has something to do with line 78, where I set the labels' size, but changing it does not seem to work. The dragging feature seems to work fine so I think line 27 to 42 is okay. I could be wrong and not seeing the issue, but this is what I have done. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. The issue was that the storyboard's constraints were conflicting with the CGSize width and height, 5 lines from the bottom. Thus I changed the storyboard constraints to the size I wanted and did the "self.view.frame.size.width/5" for height by changing the width to height within the code. That way, it matched up. The other you to consider the label of the collection view location, but it is not hard to deal with from my experience. I hope this answer helps those who come across this post.